# Using the For Loop alongside Rest Parameters

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Having a complete and utter brain fart here

Why are we doing sum = sum + numbers[i].

I've even looked at the result if we do sum = numbers[i] or sum = sum + numbers and for the life of me can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated

```
const add = function (...numbers) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) sum += numbers[i];
  console.log(sum);
};

add(2, 3);
add(5, 3, 7, 2);
add(8, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4);
```

Comment: `sum = numbers[i]` will only ever result in `sum` being the last value passed. It's really not clear what you're asking though. Could you please [edit] your question for clarity?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [MDN docs for *Rest parameters*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters?retiredLocale=de)

> The rest parameter syntax allows a function to accept an indefinite number of arguments as an array, providing a way to represent variadic functions in JavaScript.

That essentially means that rest parameters are just some syntactic sugar and equivalent to the following:

```js
const add = function (numbers) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) sum += numbers[i];
  console.log(sum);
};

add([2, 3]);
add([5, 3, 7, 2]);
add([8, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4]);
```

With `numbers[i]` you get the value at the `i`-th position in the array and `sum += numbers[i]` is short for `sum = sum + numbers[i]`, meaning that `add()` will sum up all the values (from index `0` to index `numbers.length - 1`) in the array and the total value will be logged to the console.